# Pick up email address if the cell contains a formula that pulls the email address from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a table that contains email address. These are pulled from other sheets (clients, targets, etc.).

The code does not work if the email address column contains formulas.

If I hard paste the email address, the code works.

```vb
Sub Test1()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    
    Dim strsubject As String
    For Each cell In Range("F10")
        strsubject = cell.Value
    Next
     
    Dim strbody As String
    For Each cell In Range("F13:F13")
        strbody = strbody & cell.Value & vbNewLine
    Next
     
    For Each cell In Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
            LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "y" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = strsubject
                .body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & str
                .Display 
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "the email column". Which would that be, D ?

Comment: C is the email, D is a flag

Comment: If all in column C are formulas then try `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)` instead of `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`

Comment: Do you need to use SpecialCells? Why not loop through every row in column C?

Comment: @norie Do you mean loop through 1,048,576 rows ?

Comment: No, loop through the rows with data, whether they are constants or results from formulas.

Comment: @norie I thought the rows with a formula in column C were the ones to be emailed. How else to identify the "rows with data", `end(xlUp)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the values in column C without using SpecialCells.

This will check the values in the cells regardless if they are constants or results from formulas.

```vb
For Each cell In Range("C2", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Cells
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
            LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "y" Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = strsubject
                .body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Str
                .Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell
```